# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: YEAR

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm trying to write a query from java code using SQL to find the difference in years between two date columns. I have a table `tblExportHTC` with columns `VisitDate` and `DateOfBirth` and I want to calculate the number of years between the two columns.

My java code block:

```
 try {
        String path = selectedFiles;
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + path + ";jackcessOpener=app.test.CryptCodecOpener", "", "");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT DATEDIFF(year,vis.VisitDate,vis.DateOfBirth) as date_diff "
                + " FROM tblExportHTC vis WHERE vis.ClientCode='PITC-TENT-4-093'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            int visits_count = rs.getInt("date_diff");
            System.err.println("index_pos_from_sexual_partners: " + visits_count);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Whenever I try to run the code, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: YEAR
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:216)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: YEAR
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

What I want is to get the number of years between columns `VisitDate` and `DateOfBirth`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Given the JDBC URL, the OP is using MS Access through UcanAccess (which uses HSQLDB).

Comment: I'm using to query from ms access file sir

Comment: According to [DateDiff Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-E6DD7EE6-3D01-4531-905C-E24FC238F85F) you should use `'yyyy'` instead of `year`. Not sure if that applies to the SQL syntax, or just to the VB code.

Comment: Still the same Mark Rottevel

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Yes, UCanAccess supports `DateDiff` using the Access syntax `DateDiff('yyyy', date1, date2)`. Verified with UCanAccess 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer: I have to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function instead of `DATEDIFF()` and it seems to be working perfectly.

```
try {
    String path = selectedFiles;
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + path + ";jackcessOpener=app.test.CryptCodecOpener", "", "");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,vis.VisitDate,vis.DateOfBirth) as date_diff "
            + " FROM tblExportHTC vis WHERE vis.ClientCode='PITC-TENT-4-093'");
    while (rs.next()) {
        int visits_count = rs.getInt("date_diff");
        System.err.println("index_pos_from_sexual_partners: " + visits_count);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```